# Deletion of drawing cache

Tags: android, bitmap

In my app I want to *swap images* at runtime when user clicks on it.

there are two imageviews when user click on first image and then click on second image at the same time I'm  fetching bitmap of first imageview's image and assigning to second imageview for this I used following code:

```
public Bitmap createBitmap(ImageView imageview) {
    imageview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    imageview.buildDrawingCache(false);

    if(imageview.getDrawingCache() != null) {
        Bitmap  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageview.getDrawingCache());
        imageview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return bitmap;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Code is working fine but the cache not cleared every time and the bitmap created with previous cache so how I can clear a bitmap cache?

Comment: plz use this u will get ans https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sample e.g. where i use to `Free the native object associated with this bitmap`.

```
Bitmap  bitmap;

public Bitmap createBitmap(ImageView imageview) {
    if (bitmap != null) {
        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap = null;
    }
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageview.getDrawingCache());
    // Your Code of bitmap Follows here
}
```

Before use of Bitmap just free the object.

Comment: thnx for reply...but  i  guesss i have to recycle bitmap before putting value on it,correct me if me wrong

Comment: @curious_mind : change made while allocation of bitmap at appropriate time.

Comment: Honeycomb+ bitmaps are no longer allocated in the native heap, they're now in the Dalvik heap. Calling recycle() is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

use `bitmap.recycle();` before valuating your bitmaps to clear their cache before recreating it.